# Angular Material: How to change top padding of mat-grid-tile

Tags: html, css, angular5, angular-material2

am using [angular-material](https://material.angular.io/) with angular 5. mat-grid-tile has it's own top padding that calculates using `calc` method.

I want to set custom padding on mat-grid-tile. How can i do this?

Comment: Here is a helpful link on Github regarding this: https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/11232

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The grid tile component sets top padding dynamically on the element itself, so you need to use the !important modifier in your CSS to override it.

HTML:

```
<mat-grid-tile class="my-grid-tile"></mat-grid-tile>
```

CSS:

```
.my-grid-tile {
    padding-top: 24px !important;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Setting **rowHeight** of mat-grid-list works for me, the G. Tranter doesn't work because the mat-grid-list has a padding It's set dynamically too and cannot be setted with !important.

```
 <!-- 70px to prevent hide floatLabel in matInput --> 
 <mat-grid-list cols="2" rowHeight="70px">
    <mat-grid-tile>
       <!-- your controls --> 
    </mat-grid-tile>
  </mat-grid-list>
```

Ref: https://material.angular.io/components/grid-list/examples

```
"@angular/material": "^6.4.3"
"@angular/core": "^6.1.0"
```

Answer (score 2):

To get rid of the padding on top of mat grid tile restrict the height of the mat grid tile using this line of code:

```
<mat-grid-list cols='2' rowHeight='200px'>
</mat-grid-list>
```

Increment or reduce the pixels to fit all the rows of your mat tile content.