# Remove extra padding from "mat-grid-tile"

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material

I am getting lot of extra white-space on UI, while using `mat-grid-tile` under `mat-grid-list` component of Angular Material.

```
<span *ngFor="let row of rowsArr" class="rowClass">
    <mat-grid-list cols="{{row.colsArr.length}}">
        <mat-grid-tile *ngFor="let col of row.cols">
            <app-sample-component [col]=col></app-sample-component>
        </mat-grid-tile>
    </mat-grid-list> 
</span>
```

Here above one is a sample code snippet. While inspecting in Dev Tools, I am getting that some `padding-top` and `padding-bottom` are calculating dynamically using `calc()` function of css(like - `padding-top: calc((100% - 0px) * 1 + 0px)`) and applied on UI.

I want to override or disable these kinds of CSS. 
Disabling or overriding this CSS, may resolve this issue.

Please help me, to remove these padding.

PreCondition - Please, Do not use `rowHeight` property in `mat-grid-list` component because each col has some different kind of implementation. For example - col can be a simple text component or can be a table or can be an image or can be something else.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

For overriding the applied CSS, I think you can add one class for custom styling on the tag above the mat-grid-list, and make the padding-bottom and padding-top according to your requirement. Add **!important** so that it can override the pre-applied CSS.

So your code would look like this:

```
    <span *ngFor="let row of rowsArr" class="rowClass custom">
        <mat-grid-list cols="{{row.colsArr.length}}">
            <mat-grid-tile *ngFor="let col of row.cols">
                <app-sample-component [col]=col></app-sample-component>
            </mat-grid-tile>
        </mat-grid-list> 
    </span>
```

And add the below code to your CSS file.

```
    .custom {
      mat-grid-list {
        padding-bottom: 0px !important;
      }
      mat-grid-tile{
        padding-top: 0px !important;
      }
    }
```

I hope this would solve your problem.

Comment: Hii Minal Shah, i already tried with this but it is not appplicable on UI. i even search for reason then i am getting that this padding top and bottom is calculated dynamically and you cant over write by using "!important". Anyway Thank you Minal. please let me know, if you are getting any other solution

Answer (score 0):

I searched for this problem and yes the first child and last child have padding-left and right respectively,

refer for more info:
1.) https://github.com/angular/components/issues/11232

2.) [Angular Material: How to change top padding of mat-grid-tile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49070178/angular-material-how-to-change-top-padding-of-mat-grid-tile)

You can remove these padding by applying the following code also:

```
.mat-table {
  mat-row, mat-header-row, mat-footer-row {
    padding-left: 24px;
    padding-right: 24px;
  }

  mat-cell:first-child, mat-footer-cell:first-child, mat-header-cell:first-child {
    padding-left: 0;
  }

  mat-cell:last-child, mat-footer-cell:last-child, mat-header-cell:last-child {
    padding-right: 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: Hii VR7, Thanks for your response. Yes you are right and even i already seen this on UI. But my concern is with padding top which is calculating dynamically by mat-grid-tile component. Can you pls see that.

Comment: well I am not that good in CSS but I searched and I found out the calc method can be very useful in case of many screen sizes. so here also you can make your own padding-top and padding-bottom by using calc method .look here for more info: https://css-tricks.com/a-couple-of-use-cases-for-calc/ and  https://love2dev.com/blog/css-calc/

Answer (score 0):

recommend add gutterSize

try this

```
<span *ngFor="let row of rowsArr" class="rowClass">
  <mat-grid-list cols="{{row.colsArr.length}}" gutterSize="0"> /* here edit */
    <mat-grid-tile *ngFor="let col of row.cols">
        <app-sample-component [col]=col></app-sample-component>
    </mat-grid-tile>
  </mat-grid-list> 
</span>
```

I hope this is helpful.